# Countif function in SQL

Tags: sql, count

My sample file as below (four columns):

```
ID Balance1 Balance2 Balance3
xx    -1       -1       0
yy    -1        0       1
```

Each customer is unique. I want to count the number of negative values and positive values e.g.count negative for `xx` is `2` and for `yy` is `1` while positive value (more than 0) for `xx` is `0` and `yy` is `1`.

I can use the COUNTIF function in Excel, but how can I use SQL statement?

Comment: Having multiple columns containing the same "type" of data is usually indicative of a broken data model. It looks like this should be a table of 3 columns and 6 rows - the columns being `Id`, `Balance` and whatever the name is for the *data* currently being embedded in your column *names* of 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

you should try this :

```
Select ID
    , Sum( Case When value < 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Negatives
    , Sum( Case When value > 0 Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Positive
From sample_table
Group By ID
```

Comment: When posting code, you should highlight the block and hit the `{}` button - it keeps the layout as you wrote it and allows the highlighter a chance to prettify the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

select id,   
sum (case when balance1 >0 then 1 else 0 end ) +
 sum (case when balance2 >0 then 1 else 0 end ) +
  sum (case when balance3 >0 then 1 else 0 end ) 
  as positive,

sum (case when balance1 <0 then 1 else 0 end ) +
 sum (case when balance2 <0 then 1 else 0 end ) +
  sum (case when balance3 <0 then 1 else 0 end )  as negative
from tABLE

group by id
```